# How can I run Haxe 2.10 on Travis-CI (64-bit Ubuntu)?

Tags: haxe, travis-ci

This is tricky because Haxe 2.10 is 32-bit only, so you need the right combination of 32-bit libs.

(Existing instructions on the net assume Haxe 3, e.g. http://blog.onthewings.net/2013/03/19/automated-unit-testing-for-haxe-project-using-travis-ci/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a working `.travis.yml`:

```
language: c

before_install:
- sudo apt-get update -qq

install:
- sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib -y
- sudo apt-get install libgc-dev:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpcre3:i386 -y
- curl -s -S -O http://nekovm.org/_media/neko-2.0.0-linux.tar.gz
- tar xzf neko-2.0.0-linux.tar.gz
- curl -s -S -O http://haxe.org/website-content/downloads/2,10,0/downloads/haxe-2.10-linux.tar.gz
- tar xzf haxe-2.10-linux.tar.gz

before_script:
- export NEKOPATH=$PWD/neko-2.0.0-linux
- export PATH=$PATH:$NEKOPATH
- export HAXEPATH=$PWD/haxe-2.10-linux
- export HAXE_LIBRARY_PATH=$HAXEPATH/std
- export PATH=$HAXEPATH:$PATH
- export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$NEKOPATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- mkdir ~/haxelib
- haxelib setup ~/haxelib
```

Installing `gcc-multilib` is necessary for doing almost anything with 32-bit libraries. The remaining packages are specific libraries required by Haxe and/or Neko.

Comment: I believe also that apt-get still installs Haxe 2 . It's a pretty old version though.